# systemd service file how to assign chdir for ExecStart command

Tags: systemd

In a Spring boot application, it looks for a local `resources` folder to load configurations. Therefore, its startup shell script needs to run in this folder:

```
x.jar
resources
   |- application.yml
   |- more.yml
startup.sh
```

I am writing `app.service`, and I am stuck here:

```
[Unit]
Description=service for app
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=cd /data/flume; ./control.sh start
ExecReload=cd /data/flume; ./control.sh restart
ExecStop=cd /data/flume; ./control.sh stop
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: cd /data/flume; /bin/bash startup.sh

Is it possible to have a `Chdir` in systemd? Or is there an decent way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is `[Service]` `WorkingDirectory=`.

But you'll have to specify the full path to the script anyway – ExecStart lines aren't a shell; they have their own rules that are different from shell commands.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/data/flume/control.sh start
WorkingDirectory=/data/flume
```

(Even in actual shells, you don't need to be within a directory in order to run scripts from it – you can **always** replace the `./` with the script's full path.)

---

Finally, it would be *much* preferred to launch the service directly, **without** the use of any "control.sh" or "startup.sh" wrapper scripts. If they set environment variables, you can set them in the .service as well.

Comment: One more thing just noticed, in `control.sh` it has 3 lines, first starts app, and then `sleep 3` seconds before it `grep` app's pid, if pid is empty, it assumes booting failure, so `exit 1`. This does not work in systemd? because no matter how large I set sleep timer (10 seconds) it does not grep that pid.

Comment: No, I would suspect something else (such as an _actual_ booting failure), but... does it really need to do that? Typically systemd itself can already monitor whether the app has started or not.

Comment: control.sh start app by `eval $CMD`, it first concat strings to get a CMD, and then run it by calling `eval`. is this `eval` function still valid in systemd?

Comment: Eval within a bash script is still eval within a bash script (even if it's run via systemd); but I suspect it's not eval that is the problem – it's the `nohup` and the `&` that might cause the most issues.